# There is a small glitch in my second if/else statement, I think, can you help me find it?

Tags: java

There is a small glitch in my second if/else statement, I think, can you help me find it?
The once word == 1 the value of word is supposed to change to "bottle" but it is printing "bottles."

---

```
public class milkSong
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int milkNum = 10; //decreased the bottles of milk so that the output would fit
        String word = "bottles";

        while (milkNum > 0) {

            if (milkNum == 1) { 
                word = "bottle"; 
            }

            System.out.println (milkNum + " " + word + " of milk on the wall.");
            System.out.println (milkNum + " " + word + " of milk.");
            System.out.println ("Take one down.");
            System.out.println ("Pass it around.");
            milkNum = milkNum - 1;

           //There is a problem with this statement, once beerNum == 1, still printing "bottles"
            if (milkNum > 0) { 
                System.out.println (milkNum + " " + word + " of milk on the wall.");
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println ("No more bottles of milk on the wall.");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you're setting value of `word` variable before you actually decrease `milkNum`

Comment: Thanks! I tried moving that line of to 3 different places but didn't think about putting it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the setting of `word` to be after `milkNum = milkNum -1`

Comment: A "Milk" user solving the "bottles of milk" problem. Okay. :)

Comment: i just I should added that I'm teaching myself Java and during this time I was going through if/else statements and loops. I thought this was site where I could help with this I am learning to understand...